# Can I use PySpark to extract values from JSON strings that vary in schema for each row, and place it in a column with the same name as the key?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

The API we are querying to ingest event data from returns this data in a different format depending on the event type. We have this event response stored as a `StringType()` column called `info` that needs to be converted to a `StructType()` so that we can extract values. Depending on wether the claim made was a success, failure or not applicable, the response structure for the `info` column changes as shown below:

```
Row 1: '{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null, "claims": "N/A"}'
Row 2: '{"name":"Jack", "details": {"age":25, "car":Prius, "claims": "Success"}}'
Row 3: '{"details": {"name":"James", "age":40, "car":"Porsche", "claims": "Fail"}}'
```

I want to take each key, Name, Age, Car and Claims and have a column for each one with the corresponding values for each row. This creates an problem as we need to 1. Declare a schema type for the column which is a `StructType()` of variable structure/schema, and 2. Extract the values with different traversals due to the key structure (i.e. For the name value in Row 1: `df.withColumn("name", col('info.name'))`, and for Row 2: `df.withColumn("name", col('info.details.name'))`).

Is there a way to do this without having to declare a schema for every response type and manually write different withColumn statements for every structural variation thereafter to obtain the key values. I ultimately need the table to look like:

| Name | Age | Car | Claims |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 30 | null | N/A |
| Jacks | 25 | Prius | Success |
| James | 40 | Porsche | Fail |

I have tried writing the schemas manually for each response type, but in production there are 50 of them and they will obviously have to be split into multiple columns to avoid schema conflicts. After this I would have to do a withColumn call differently for each of the 50 response types in order to complete the ingestion. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Possibly look into regex